# Azure CLI unable to create portal dashboards from templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface

Using examples verbatim with provided json, no matter how simple always result in the following.  I have been unable to find any documentation on this error.

```
PS C:\Users\X> az portal dashboard create --input-path "C:\Users\X\Downloads\test.json" --resource-group TestGroup
```

--name "testDash"
Command group 'portal' is experimental and not covered by customer support. Please use with discretion.
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\X\Downloads\test.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> does not contain the property 'lenses'

I have confirmed repeatedly that that property exists as it is also directly pulled from Microsofts own documentation here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically#create-a-template-from-the-json

Answer (score 3):

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\X\Downloads\test.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> does not contain the property 'lenses'

Based on my test, I could reproduce the same issue.

[image]

In the Json file , the lenses property indeed exists. So this issue exists in the azure cli command itself.

I have reported this issue in the feedback interface of azure cli in Github.

[Azure CLI issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16356)

**Update:**

> az portal dashboard create, the --input-path is the path to properties json file instead of full template

The Azure CLI Command: `az portal dashboard create` will read the `properties -> lenses` instead of the whole template.

To solve this issue, we need to remove other parameters and keep `lenses` parameter.

Here is my example:

```
{
    "lenses": {
      "0": {
        "order": 0,
        "parts": {}
      }
    },
    "metadata": {
      "model": {
        "timeRange": {
          "value": {
            "relative": {
              "duration": 24,
              "timeUnit": 1
            }
          },
          "type": "MsPortalFx.Composition.Configuration.ValueTypes.TimeRange"
        }
      }
    }
 
}
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for confirming im not loosing my mind!  I appreciate the added effort to open an issue.

Comment: @ShawnMahoney Glad to know that it could give you some help ! You can follow the update of the Github question . If there are any updates, I will post it here too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the feedback option at the bottom of the page to file a issue in GitHub for assistance.